# Kotlin coroutine won't compile without delay (suspend function?)

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I was going through the Kotlin coroutine examples and was playing with this example.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        repeat(1000) {i->
            println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
            delay(500)
        }
    }
    delay(1300)
}
```

It works as the example expected, printing 3 times and terminating. How ever if the last line, delay(1300), is removed, the program will not recognise the main function and not compile. Why is this?

Replacing the last line with println() still compiles but only prints once.

Comment: what's version of coroutine module you are using?

Comment: I am using 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of return types.

`main` function should return `Unit` type.

In Kotlin

> We can explicitly return a value from the lambda using the qualified return syntax. **Otherwise, the value of the last expression is implicitly returned.**

*See [Returning a value from a lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression)*

If the the `delay` call removed the outer lambda's(`runBlocking`) return type changed to [`Job`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) (`launch` functions's return value) and `main` also returns `Job`.

So it fails to run

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        repeat(1000) {i->
            println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
            delay(500)
        }
    }
    delay(1300) // returns Unit, runBlocking also returns Unit and so does main
}
```

With `delay` removed:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        repeat(1000) {i->
            println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
            delay(500)
        }
    } // returns Job, runBlocking also returns Job and so does main
}
```

Comment: Makes sense :) if you return a string from ```runBlocking``` you get an error saying ```main should return a unit```. Thankyou.